# Multiple Typescript compilers on one machine

Tags: typescript, build-server

I want to have typescript  compiled to javascript on my buildserver.

There are multiple applications that need to be build with distinct versions of the typescript compiler.

Is ist possible to have mulitple versions of the compiler on a machine and how do I specify which to use?

Comment: *...how do I specify which to use* would be difficult to answer without knowing what build server you are using.

Comment: It would be sufficient for me to know the command line commands for windows

Answer (score 3):

Sure, install typescript locally through npm to each application and build using the compiler instance in `node_modules/typescript/bin/tsc`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The simplest way would be adding `typescript` to dependencies of each project, instead of `npm install -g`.

After that you can call tsc command in `npm run` (this sets $PATH for you).